# How to capture selected Column from array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an array `data` captured from a googlesheet.

My Spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOI');
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
 var data = sheet.getDataRange.getValues();
```

Now I want to filter/capture selected column:

col 1, col3, col4 and all the column where week = 5 (Col H & Col I) and class = 2.

filter method can filter the data horizontally. but how to filter vertically.

`data = data.filter(function(item){return item[1] == 2}); //here I can filter where class=2`

But I want to filter the column according to row 3 where week = 5.

*Note that the date Range here is just an example it could be of any size. I have date range in variables If the date as variable say  `x = 2/1/2020 y =2/30/2020`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might work and if you want me to test it then post me some csv data of you Spreadsheet. I tested it with the data below.

```
function mifunc() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getDisplayValues();
  var hA1=vA.shift();//Row one
  vA.shift();
  var hA3=vA.shift();//Row three
  const idx1={};//this will return array indices when you access the properties because the properties are the strings in row 
  const idx3={};
  hA1.forEach(function(h,i){idx1[h]=i;});//this does the column header to index assignment for the columns in row3
  hA3.forEach(function(h,i){idx3[h]=i;});
  var data=vA.map(function(r){if(r[idx3['Class']]==2){return [r[0],r[2],r[3],r[idx1['2/1/2020']],r[idx1['2/2/2020']]];}}).filter(function(e){return e;});
  const end="is near";//just a break point to stop on
}
```

Data:

```
,,,,,,,2/1/2020,2/2/2020,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
COL1,Class,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8,COL9,COL10,COL11,COL12,COL13,COL14,COL15
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,D,D,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,D,D,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
```

Result:

```
2,2,2,D,D
2,2,2,D,D
```

This might work for your extended needs:

```
function mifunc() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const rg=sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow()-2,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getDisplayValues();
  var hA3=vA.shift();//Row three
  const idx3={};
  hA3.forEach(function(h,i){idx3[h]=i;});
  var data=vA.map(function(r,i){
    if(r[idx3['Class']]==2){
      const keep=new Set([0,2,3])
      var row=[];
      r.forEach(function(c,j){
        if(keep.has(j) || hA3[j]==5) {
          row.push(c);
        }
      });            
    return row;
  }}).filter(function(e){return e;});
  const end="is near";//just a break point to stop on
}
```

Comment: First of all Thankyou for your reply. But In this solution we have defined col H and I `r[col1['2/1/2020']],r[col1['2/2/2020']]` but there could be situation where I have to select entire Month. In that case I have to write it 30 times.

Comment: If I pass the date as variable say  `x = 2/1/2020 y =2/30/2020 ` can we write the code as

Comment: Put that into the question

Comment: Well I'll just leave the rest for you to figure out.

Comment: thank you. I will try to figure out what can be next.

Comment: what I did next was created an array of row matching the dates but I am finding hard to insert that array as row number. `if (new Date(data[0][i]) >= new Date('2/1/2020') && new Date(data[0][i]) < new Date('3/1/2020'))
        indexes.push('r['+i+']');}` by indexes has now values `[r[58], r[59], r[60], r[61],....r[86]]'` then I tried to put that array in your code like this `var data2=vA.map(function(r){if(r[idx3['Class']]==2){return [r[0],r[2],r[3],indexes]]];}}).filter(function(e){return e;});` but it just return the row number and not columns.

Comment: Could you please guide how to make indexes array behave like literal values.

Comment: If you're going to post that much code then post it in your question please.